# Configuration 'production' could not be found in project 'my-lib'

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-library

I am building a library with Angular 6.1.0

- `ng new lib-demo`
- `ng generate library my-lib`

All the articles advise running the build for the library with a `--prod` flag like so:

```
ng build my-lib --prod
```

However, this throws an error

```
Configuration 'production' could not be found in project 'my-lib'.
```

Which is probably correct because when I look at the **angular.json** there is no definition for a `production build configuration` in the library project. It is present for the application project only.

the following is what I have under the build configuration for library project that uses `ng-packagr`

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/my-lib/ng-package.json"
      }
    }
```

So the question here is that is the `--prod` flag not required anymore and just running `ng build m-lib` will generate a prod build?

Looking at the contents of dist folder it looks so but I am not 100% sure. If someone could validate this, it will be great.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Beginning with version 6.1, Angular always does a production build of our library, i.e. in new versions of Angular we don't need the `--prod` flag anymore when building it, libraries are always built in AOT mode. To ensure, you can take a look at these issues in Angular-CLI repository:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12290

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12226

And this article (*"Building the Library"* section):

https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

***If you are still using version 6.0.x (or lower) you will want to use the --prod flag when building your library.***

You still have an option to pass a `configuration` as a parameter if needed: `ng build --configuration=configuration` (see [docs](https://angular.io/cli/build)). If necessary, you can specify build rules in `angular.json`, for example, for `production` build:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        // Options here
    }
}
```

And the command should be `ng build --configuration=production`.

Comment: Thanks for validating it. I suspected that it did but wanted to be sure

Answer (score 19):

In Angular 6+ it is `ng build --configuration=production`

Then put a production configuration in angular.json

```
 "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
```

Comment: Having same issue, this solution doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

under the architect section look for "configurations", if you don't have any. try adding one like below.

```
"configurations": {
      "production": {
      "project": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/ng-package.json"
    }
}

your architect section should like this



"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "project": "projects/PROJECT-NAME/ng-package.json"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the --prod is no longer needed as the library is always build in AOT mode and without the --prod You need to run only ng build

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Is there any supporting Angular document which clarifies more aspects