# Using environment variables in nx based nodejs app

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, nrwl, nrwl-nx

I've setup a project with several nodejs and angular apps inside a nrwl/nx workspace.

I'm trying to work with the environment files 
inside the nodejs apps.

I've setup the import like this:
`import {environment} from './environments/environment';`

Then I ran `ng serve my-node-app` and it shows the environment for non production.

Now I tried to do `ng serve my-node-app --prod` to see how the app works with a production setup - but I get the error:

`Configuration 'production' could not be found in project my-node-app`.

Here's the project's angular.json config:

```
"ui-server": {
      "root": "apps/ui/server",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/ui/server/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "ui-server",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/builders:node-build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/apps/ui/server",
            "main": "apps/ui/server/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/ui/server/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["apps/ui/server/src/assets"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/ui/server/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/ui/server/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/builders:node-execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "ui-server:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "apps/ui/server/tsconfig.app.json",
              "apps/ui/server/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/builders:jest",
          "options": {
            "jestConfig": "apps/ui/server/jest.config.js",
            "tsConfig": "apps/ui/server/tsconfig.spec.json"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52319576/configuration-production-could-not-be-found-in-project-my-lib

Comment: @WillCain - I do not believe this is a duplicate. For once, the mentioned topic does not answer my questions. Second - it talks about a lib in an angular project. I'm talking about a nodejs app inside a nrwl/nx project.

Comment: There is more information in that linked thread. The `--prod` is not needed any more as it is always aot compiled. What we're doing here is `--configuration=producttion` which requires a `production` entry in the build section of your app in `angular.json`. Can you post the architect config for your app so we can better assist?

Comment: @electrichead thanks. I've added the config to the question. It seems like the configuration is already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this post when I was looking how to fetch the environmental variables defined in `.env` file.

`process.env.ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLES` in frontend part can be accessed when rendering on the server (e.g. `Angular Universal`), having `.env` in the root of `Nrwl` monorepo and webpack properties, such as:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new dotenv(),
  ],
};
```

Don't forget to change your `angular.json`:

```
...
"architect": {
  "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
       "options": {
         "customWebpackConfig": {
           "path": "./webpack.browser.config.js",
           "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
          },
          ...
```

I've named the custom `webpack` as `webpack.browser.config.js`.

Now, let say you have a `server/...`, which you're using for some backend stuff, then you won't have them accessible there. You need to install `dotenv` package and in the `server/main.ts`, let say that's your server's root, require this package, that way:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

**Note:** until `Angular 8` we were able to set up also `webpack`-server related logic, in a file such as `webpack.server.config.js`. Therefore, it was doable to apply basically same code related to `dotenv`, which was in `webpack.browser.config.js`. However, [it doesn't work anymore](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16348). [Angular CLI Builders are being used to build & server SSR apps instead](https://github.com/nestjs/ng-universal/issues/418#issuecomment-688170340).

Deploying to `Firebase`/using `Cloud Functions for Firebase` (and possibly other Serverless/FaaS)?

Then in your `functions` folder you need to paste the `.env` file as well. I assume here that from `functions` you're deploying.

For debugging I'd advise:

```
console.log(require('dotenv').config({ debug: true }));
```

Might save you **a lot** of time.